# Input major type table to procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, performance, types

I'm trying to read XML data from my backend and pass the data to the procedure as typetable. When I try it with small XML data (500KB with 1000 rows) the procedure work correctly. But when I use it with 60MB XML it never responds and also everyone who works on dev database can't modify the procedure and the service never responds again. How should I use a big XML input as a type without performance issues?

EDIT: it worked for one week but suddenly it won't no more

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [COR].[INSERT_BIC_CODES_TEST] 
@BICCODES_TABLE COR.BICCODES_TYPE_TABLE READONLY, 
@ADDED_CODES_COUNT VARCHAR(MAX) 
OUTPUT 
AS 
  BEGIN 

        EXEC TRE.GENERAL_LOG_INSERT 'BATCH','COR.INSERT_BIC_CODES_TEST','ILK LOG',''

          DECLARE @ADDEDCOUNT INT = 0
          DECLARE @UPDATEDCOUNT INT = 0
          DECLARE @DELETEDCOUNT INT = 0

          DECLARE @MODIFICATION_FLAG CHAR(1)
          DECLARE @BANK_CODE CHAR(4) 
          DECLARE @COUNTRY_CODE CHAR(2) 
          DECLARE @CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE CHAR(5) 
          DECLARE @BANK_NAME VARCHAR(100) 
          DECLARE @CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME VARCHAR(40) 
          DECLARE @COUNTRY_NAME VARCHAR(50) 
          DECLARE @CITY_NAME VARCHAR(40) 
          DECLARE @ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE CHAR(3) 
          DECLARE @OUR_ACCOUNT_NO INT 
          DECLARE @SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG CHAR(1) 
          DECLARE @COUNTRY_RISK VARCHAR(10) 
          DECLARE @ADDRESS VARCHAR(80) 
          DECLARE @AUTHENTICATION_FLAG CHAR(1) 
          DECLARE @LAST_UPDATING_CHANNEL_CODE CHAR(10) 
          DECLARE @LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE CHAR(6) 
          DECLARE @LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE VARCHAR(50) 
          DECLARE @LAST_UPDATE_DATE DATETIME 
          DECLARE @RECORD_STATUS CHAR(1) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_1 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_2 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_3 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_4 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_5 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_6 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_7 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @COUNTRY_CODE_NUMBER INT 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_8 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_9 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_10 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_11 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_12 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_13 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_14 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_15 VARCHAR(20) 

          DECLARE BICCODETMPCURSOR CURSOR FOR
            SELECT 
          CAST(MODIFICATION_FLAG AS CHAR),
          CAST(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(BIC_CODE)),0, 5) AS CHAR(4)) BANK_CODE,
          CAST(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(BIC_CODE)),5, 2) AS CHAR(2)) COUNTRY_CODE,
          CAST((SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(BIC_CODE)),7, 2) + BRANCH_CODE) AS CHAR(5)) CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE,
          CAST(INSTITUTION_NAME AS VARCHAR(100)) BANK_NAME,
          CAST(BRANCH_INFORMATION AS VARCHAR(40)) CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME,
          CAST(ISNULL(COUNTRY_NAME,'') AS VARCHAR(50)) COUNTRY_NAME,
          CAST(CITY_HEADING AS VARCHAR(40)) CITY_NAME,
          CAST('' AS CHAR(3))ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE,
          CAST(NULL AS INT)OUR_ACCOUNT_NO,
          CAST('' AS CHAR(1))SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10))COUNTRY_RISK,
          ISNULL(CAST(PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_1 + ' ' + PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_2 + ' ' + PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_3 + ' ' + PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_4 AS VARCHAR(80)),'EMPTY ADRESS') ADDRESS,
          CAST(NULL AS CHAR(1)) AUTHENTICATION_FLAG,
          CAST('XPORT' AS CHAR(10)) LAST_UPDATING_CHANEL_CODE,
          CAST('XPORT' AS CHAR(6)) LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE,
          CAST('XPORT' AS VARCHAR(50)) LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE,
          GETDATE() LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
          CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(20)) RECORD_STATUS,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_1,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_2,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_3,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_4,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_5,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_6,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_7,
          CAST(NULL AS INT) COUNTRY_CODE_NUMBER,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_8,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_9,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_10,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_11,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_12,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_13,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_14,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_15
          FROM  @BICCODES_TABLE 


      OPEN BICCODETMPCURSOR 

      FETCH NEXT FROM BICCODETMPCURSOR INTO @MODIFICATION_FLAG,@BANK_CODE,@COUNTRY_CODE,@CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE,@BANK_NAME,@CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME,@COUNTRY_NAME,@CITY_NAME,
                                            @ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE ,@OUR_ACCOUNT_NO,@SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG ,@COUNTRY_RISK,@ADDRESS ,@AUTHENTICATION_FLAG ,@LAST_UPDATING_CHANNEL_CODE,
                                            @LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE,@LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE ,@LAST_UPDATE_DATE,@RECORD_STATUS,@ROUTERS_CODE_1,@ROUTERS_CODE_2,@ROUTERS_CODE_3,@ROUTERS_CODE_4,
                                            @ROUTERS_CODE_5,@ROUTERS_CODE_6,@ROUTERS_CODE_7,@COUNTRY_CODE_NUMBER,@ROUTERS_CODE_8,@ROUTERS_CODE_9,@ROUTERS_CODE_10 ,@ROUTERS_CODE_11 ,@ROUTERS_CODE_12 ,
                                            @ROUTERS_CODE_13 ,@ROUTERS_CODE_14 ,@ROUTERS_CODE_15

          EXEC TRE.GENERAL_LOG_INSERT 'BATCH','COR.INSERT_BIC_CODES_TEST','GIRDI',''

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN 
            IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TRE.CORRESPONDENT_BANK_DEFINITION WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE  BANK_CODE = @BANK_CODE AND COUNTRY_CODE = @COUNTRY_CODE AND  CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE = @CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE)
                BEGIN

                    UPDATE TRE.CORRESPONDENT_BANK_DEFINITION 
                    SET    
                           BANK_CODE = @BANK_CODE, 
                           COUNTRY_CODE = @COUNTRY_CODE,
                           CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE = @CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE, 
                           BANK_NAME = @BANK_NAME, 
                           CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME = @CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME, 
                           COUNTRY_NAME = @COUNTRY_NAME, 
                           CITY_NAME = @CITY_NAME, 
                           ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE = @ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE, 
                           OUR_ACCOUNT_NO = @OUR_ACCOUNT_NO, 
                           SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG = @SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG, 
                           COUNTRY_RISK = @COUNTRY_RISK, 
                           ADDRESS = @ADDRESS,
                           AUTHENTICATION_FLAG = @AUTHENTICATION_FLAG, 
                           LAST_UPDATING_CHANNEL_CODE = @LAST_UPDATING_CHANNEL_CODE, 
                           LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE = @LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE, 
                           LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE = @LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE, 
                           LAST_UPDATE_DATE = @LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 
                           RECORD_STATUS = CASE 
                           WHEN @MODIFICATION_FLAG ='A'-- added
                             OR @MODIFICATION_FLAG ='M'-- modified
                             OR @MODIFICATION_FLAG ='U'-- unchanged 
                             THEN 'A'
                             ELSE 'P' -- deleted
                           END
                    WHERE  BANK_CODE= @BANK_CODE 
                    AND    COUNTRY_CODE = @COUNTRY_CODE     
                    AND    CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE = @CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE 



                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    --ILK DEFA KAYIT
                    --XML'de OLAN BIC CODElar BIZIM TABLOLARIMIZDA YOKSA; modification_flag : 'A' , 'M' , 'U'  için record_status = 'A' // modification_flag : 'D' için record_status = 'P' olacak sekilde insert et
                    INSERT INTO TRE.CORRESPONDENT_BANK_DEFINITION 
                            (BANK_CODE, 
                             COUNTRY_CODE, 
                             CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE, 
                             BANK_NAME, 
                             CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME, 
                             COUNTRY_NAME, 
                             CITY_NAME, 
                             ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE, 
                             OUR_ACCOUNT_NO, 
                             SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG, 
                             COUNTRY_RISK, 
                             ADDRESS, 
                             AUTHENTICATION_FLAG, 
                             LAST_UPDATING_CHANNEL_CODE, 
                             LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE, 
                             LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE, 
                             LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 
                             RECORD_STATUS) 
                VALUES      
                            (@BANK_CODE, 
                             @COUNTRY_CODE, 
                             @CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE, 
                             @BANK_NAME, 
                             @CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME, 
                             @COUNTRY_NAME, 
                             @CITY_NAME, 
                             @ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE, 
                             @OUR_ACCOUNT_NO, 
                             @SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG, 
                             @COUNTRY_RISK, 
                             @ADDRESS, 
                             @AUTHENTICATION_FLAG, 
                             @LAST_UPDATING_CHANNEL_CODE, 
                             @LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE, 
                             @LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE, 
                             @LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 
                             CASE WHEN
                                @MODIFICATION_FLAG ='A'  -- ADDED
                                OR @MODIFICATION_FLAG ='M' -- MODIFIED  
                                OR @MODIFICATION_FLAG ='U' -- UNCHANGED
                                THEN 'A' 
                                ELSE 'P' --DELETED
                             END)


                    --ISLEME GÖRE OUTPUT MESAJI OLUSTURULUR

                        IF @MODIFICATION_FLAG = 'A'  OR  @MODIFICATION_FLAG = 'M' OR  @MODIFICATION_FLAG = 'U'
                            SET @ADDEDCOUNT = @ADDEDCOUNT + 1

              END 

            FETCH NEXT FROM BICCODETMPCURSOR INTO @MODIFICATION_FLAG,@BANK_CODE,@COUNTRY_CODE,@CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE,@BANK_NAME,@CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME,@COUNTRY_NAME,@CITY_NAME,
                                            @ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE ,@OUR_ACCOUNT_NO,@SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG ,@COUNTRY_RISK,@ADDRESS ,@AUTHENTICATION_FLAG ,@LAST_UPDATING_CHANNEL_CODE,
                                            @LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE,@LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE ,@LAST_UPDATE_DATE,@RECORD_STATUS,@ROUTERS_CODE_1,@ROUTERS_CODE_2,@ROUTERS_CODE_3,@ROUTERS_CODE_4,
                                            @ROUTERS_CODE_5,@ROUTERS_CODE_6,@ROUTERS_CODE_7,@COUNTRY_CODE_NUMBER,@ROUTERS_CODE_8,@ROUTERS_CODE_9,@ROUTERS_CODE_10 ,@ROUTERS_CODE_11 ,@ROUTERS_CODE_12 ,
                                            @ROUTERS_CODE_13 ,@ROUTERS_CODE_14 ,@ROUTERS_CODE_15
        END
```

What I'm basically trying to do is compare my table and XML data then delete add or update. Consider the input is 60MB XML via type table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [COR].[INSERT_BIC_CODES_TEST_V3] 
@BICCODES_TABLE COR.BICCODES_TYPE_TABLE READONLY, 
@ADDED_CODES_COUNT VARCHAR(MAX) -
OUTPUT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
        DECLARE @TRAN VARCHAR(100)
        SELECT @TRAN = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@@TRANCOUNT)
        EXEC TRE.GENERAL_LOG_INSERT 'BATCH','COR.INSERT_BIC_CODES_TEST','ILK LOG',''
        EXEC TRE.GENERAL_LOG_INSERT 'BATCH','COR.INSERT_BIC_CODES_TEST',@TRAN,''

          DECLARE @ADDEDCOUNT INT = 0
          DECLARE @UPDATEDCOUNT INT = 0
          DECLARE @DELETEDCOUNT INT = 0

          DECLARE @MODIFICATION_FLAG CHAR(1)
          DECLARE @BANK_CODE CHAR(4) 
          DECLARE @COUNTRY_CODE CHAR(2) 
          DECLARE @CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE CHAR(5) 
          DECLARE @BANK_NAME VARCHAR(100) 
          DECLARE @CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME VARCHAR(40) 
          DECLARE @COUNTRY_NAME VARCHAR(50) 
          DECLARE @CITY_NAME VARCHAR(40) 
          DECLARE @ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE CHAR(3) 
          DECLARE @OUR_ACCOUNT_NO INT 
          DECLARE @SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG CHAR(1) 
          DECLARE @COUNTRY_RISK VARCHAR(10) 
          DECLARE @ADDRESS VARCHAR(80) 
          DECLARE @AUTHENTICATION_FLAG CHAR(1) 
          DECLARE @LAST_UPDATING_CHANNEL_CODE CHAR(10) 
          DECLARE @LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE CHAR(6) 
          DECLARE @LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE VARCHAR(50) 
          DECLARE @LAST_UPDATE_DATE DATETIME 
          DECLARE @RECORD_STATUS CHAR(1) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_1 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_2 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_3 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_4 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_5 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_6 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_7 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @COUNTRY_CODE_NUMBER INT 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_8 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_9 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_10 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_11 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_12 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_13 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_14 VARCHAR(20) 
          DECLARE @ROUTERS_CODE_15 VARCHAR(20) 

            SELECT 
          MODIFICATION_FLAG=CAST(MODIFICATION_FLAG AS CHAR),
          CAST(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(BIC_CODE)),0, 5) AS CHAR(4)) BANK_CODE,
          CAST(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(BIC_CODE)),5, 2) AS CHAR(2)) COUNTRY_CODE,
          CAST((SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(BIC_CODE)),7, 2) + BRANCH_CODE) AS CHAR(5)) CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE,
          CAST(INSTITUTION_NAME AS VARCHAR(100)) BANK_NAME,
          CAST(BRANCH_INFORMATION AS VARCHAR(40)) CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME,
          CAST(ISNULL(COUNTRY_NAME,'') AS VARCHAR(50)) COUNTRY_NAME,
          CAST(CITY_HEADING AS VARCHAR(40)) CITY_NAME,
          CAST('' AS CHAR(3))ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE,
          CAST(NULL AS INT)OUR_ACCOUNT_NO,
          CAST('' AS CHAR(1))SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10))COUNTRY_RISK,
          ISNULL(CAST(PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_1 + ' ' + PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_2 + ' ' + PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_3 + ' ' + PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_4 AS VARCHAR(80)),'EMPTY ADRESS') ADDRESS,
          CAST(NULL AS CHAR(1)) AUTHENTICATION_FLAG,
          CAST('XPORT' AS CHAR(10)) LAST_UPDATING_CHANEL_CODE,
          CAST('XPORT' AS CHAR(6)) LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE,
          CAST('XPORT' AS VARCHAR(50)) LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE,
          GETDATE() LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
          CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(20)) RECORD_STATUS,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_1,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_2,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_3,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_4,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_5,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_6,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_7,
          CAST(NULL AS INT) COUNTRY_CODE_NUMBER,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_8,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_9,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_10,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_11,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_12,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_13,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_14,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) ROUTERS_CODE_15
          INTO #BICCODES_TABLE2
          FROM  @BICCODES_TABLE 

                     UPDATE F
                    SET    
                           BANK_CODE = T.BANK_CODE, 
                           COUNTRY_CODE =T.COUNTRY_CODE,
                           CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE = T.CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE, 
                           BANK_NAME = T.BANK_NAME, 
                           CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME = T.CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME, 
                           COUNTRY_NAME = T.COUNTRY_NAME, 
                           CITY_NAME = T.CITY_NAME, 
                           ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE = T.ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE, 
                           OUR_ACCOUNT_NO = T.OUR_ACCOUNT_NO, 
                           SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG = T.SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG, 
                           COUNTRY_RISK = T.COUNTRY_RISK, 
                           ADDRESS = T.ADDRESS,
                           AUTHENTICATION_FLAG = T.AUTHENTICATION_FLAG, 
                           LAST_UPDATING_CHANNEL_CODE = T.LAST_UPDATING_CHANEL_CODE, 
                           LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE = T.LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE, 
                           LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE = T.LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE, 
                           LAST_UPDATE_DATE = T.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 
                           RECORD_STATUS = CASE 
                           WHEN T.MODIFICATION_FLAG ='A'-- added
                             OR T.MODIFICATION_FLAG ='M'-- modified
                             OR T.MODIFICATION_FLAG ='U'-- unchanged 
                             THEN 'A'
                             ELSE 'P' -- deleted
                           END
                    FROM TRE.CORRESPONDENT_BANK_DEFINITION F
                    INNER JOIN #BICCODES_TABLE2 T ON( F.BANK_CODE = T.BANK_CODE AND F.COUNTRY_CODE = T.COUNTRY_CODE AND  F.CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE = T.CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE)



DECLARE  @MODIFY_COUNT INT=0
SELECT @MODIFY_COUNT= @@ROWCOUNT



     INSERT INTO TRE.CORRESPONDENT_BANK_DEFINITION 
                            (BANK_CODE, 
                             COUNTRY_CODE, 
                             CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE, 
                             BANK_NAME, 
                             CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME, 
                             COUNTRY_NAME, 
                             CITY_NAME, 
                             ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE, 
                             OUR_ACCOUNT_NO, 
                             SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG, 
                             COUNTRY_RISK, 
                             ADDRESS, 
                             AUTHENTICATION_FLAG, 
                             LAST_UPDATING_CHANNEL_CODE, 
                             LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE, 
                             LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE, 
                             LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 
                             RECORD_STATUS) 
                select      
                            T.BANK_CODE, 
                             T.COUNTRY_CODE, 
                             T.CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE, 
                             T.BANK_NAME, 
                             T.CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME, 
                             T.COUNTRY_NAME, 
                             T.CITY_NAME, 
                             T.ORIGINAL_COUNTRY_CODE, 
                             T.OUR_ACCOUNT_NO, 
                             T.SECRETARY_GUARANTEE_FLAG, 
                             T.COUNTRY_RISK, 
                             T.ADDRESS, 
                             T.AUTHENTICATION_FLAG, 
                             T.LAST_UPDATING_CHANEL_CODE, 
                             T.LAST_UPDATING_TRAN_CODE, 
                             T.LAST_UPDATING_USER_CODE, 
                             T.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 
                             CASE WHEN
                                T.MODIFICATION_FLAG ='A'  -- ADDED
                                OR T.MODIFICATION_FLAG ='M' -- MODIFIED  
                                OR T.MODIFICATION_FLAG ='U' -- UNCHANGED
                                THEN 'A' 
                                ELSE 'P' --DELETED
                             END

                 FROM #BICCODES_TABLE2 T
                 LEFT JOIN TRE.CORRESPONDENT_BANK_DEFINITION F ON( F.BANK_CODE = T.BANK_CODE AND    F.COUNTRY_CODE = T.COUNTRY_CODE AND  F.CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE = T.CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE)
                 WHERE F.BANK_CODE IS NULL


DECLARE  @ADDED_COUNT INT=0
SELECT @ADDED_COUNT= @@ROWCOUNT



          SET @ADDED_CODES_COUNT = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@ADDED_COUNT) + '%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@MODIFY_COUNT) + '%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@DELETEDCOUNT)
          SELECT @ADDED_CODES_COUNT

          EXEC TRE.GENERAL_LOG_INSERT 'BATCH','COR.INSERT_BIC_CODES_TEST','FETCH BITTI',''

          -- tablomuzda pasif olan kayıtları adk tablosundan sil(her ihtimale karşı)
          TRUNCATE TABLE FORTUNA_CONSEPT.PARAMETERS.correspondentbanklist

          INSERT INTO FORTUNA_CONSEPT.PARAMETERS.correspondentbanklist
          SELECT  
          CAST(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(BIC_CODE)),5, 2) AS CHAR(2)) COUNTRY_CODE,
          CAST(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(BIC_CODE)),0, 5) AS CHAR(4)) BANK_CODE,
          CAST(INSTITUTION_NAME AS VARCHAR(100)) BANK_NAME,
          CAST((SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(BIC_CODE)),7, 2) + BRANCH_CODE) AS CHAR(5)) CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE,
          CAST(BRANCH_INFORMATION AS VARCHAR(40)) CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_NAME
          FROM @BICCODES_TABLE WHERE CAST(MODIFICATION_FLAG AS CHAR) <> 'D'


          UPDATE C SET C.RECORD_STATUS = 'P'
          FROM TRE.CORRESPONDENT_BANK_DEFINITION C WITH (NOLOCK)
          LEFT JOIN FORTUNA_CONSEPT.PARAMETERS.correspondentbanklist F WITH (NOLOCK) ON F.BankCode = C.BANK_CODE 
                                                                      AND F.CountryCode = C.COUNTRY_CODE
                                                                      AND F.BranchCode = C.CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE
                                                                      WHERE F.BankCode IS NULL

  END
```

EDIT: Without cursor it continues to give same issue.

Comment: Is anyone running profiler traces on the server, by any chance? Combining these with big table-valued parameters can cause performance problems exactly like these.

Comment: 60MB is a pretty big XML file (Over 30,000,00 characters long). Any processing of that, depending on what it's doing, could be awhile. You should, however, really be sharing your SQL here. We can't help you if we don't know what it is your doing.

Comment: Is anyone managing the sql server? What is the recovery model of the db?

Comment: Added the code but its too long. I tried cursor alternatives but it doesnt change the performance. Main problem is i cant pass the 60mb data to Procedure

Comment: Tried to watch the sp from profiler but didn't see mine cause as i say procudure didn't execute while trying to get the data

Comment: Can't you upload/store that fairly large amount of data into a temp table and then use that from your procedure?

Comment: The fact that you are using a `CURSOR`is already a "red flag" in my mind; a `CURSOR` is inherently slow in an RDBMS as they excel at set based operations. Personally my first step would be to try and get rid of that cursor and see how well the process performs after that.

Comment: Changed cursor but nothing changed. I think its about memory issue

Comment: Break the file up into smaller files and experiment with those. Is there a linear relationship between the size of the file and the amount of time that it takes to finish processing? At what file size does the server enter into an unrecoverable state?

Comment: Note that "trying to watch the sp from profiler" would trigger exactly the problem you'd be trying to find. Use `select * from sys.traces` instead. Normally there's just one trace, the default one (which will not cause any performance issues). If there are others, you can use `sp_trace_setstatus` to stop them.

Comment: You don't have any indexes on #BICCODES_TABLE2 so the joins on BANK_CODE, COUNTRY_CODE, CORRESPONDENT_BRANCH_CODE will cause table scans on it. What's the likelihood that TRE.CORRESPONDENT_BANK_DEFINITION is also missing a covering index for the same joins?